# Galatians 5:18 vs. John 3:16

Tags: john, contradiction, galatians, soteriology

[Galations 5:18-21](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Galatians+5%3A18-21&version=NET) states

> But if you are led by the Spirit, you are not under the law. Now the works of the flesh are obvious: sexual immorality, impurity, depravity, idolatry, sorcery, hostilities, strife, jealousy, outbursts of anger, selfish rivalries, dissensions, factions, envying, murder, drunkenness, carousing, and similar things. I am warning you, as I had warned you before: **Those who practice such things will not inherit the kingdom of God!**

Yet, in [John 3:16 it states](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=John+3%3A16&version=NET)

> For this is the way God loved the world: He gave his one and only Son, so that **everyone who believes in him will not perish but have eternal life.**

These seem to be conflicting. How are we to interpret one in light of the other?

Comment: Please [edit] this question to quote from the translation you have been reading, and try to explain a little more what your question is.

Comment: The apparent contradiction is that John 3:16 appears to be unconditional - that faith alone is adequate to receive eternal life, even for someone who fails in any of the ways listed in Galatians 5:18-21. In Galations 5:18-21, the kingdom of God is conditional and apparently faith alone is not adequate. So the question is if "the kingdom of God" and the "eternal life" are equivalent or at least co-contingent, or if they mean two completely different things.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion Galations 5:18-21 look more like a definition. But this goes close to the art of application of the Biblical texts and not to find a translation misunderstanding.

To confirm and extend H3br3wHamm3r81 point of view look at [James 2:17](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=James%202%3A17&version=NET).

> So also faith, if it does not have works, is dead being by itself.

This means **"to believe"** includes more than "to say so". Instead you have **"to live the way of jesus"** to inherit the kingdom of God.

And that's what Paul want to remember the Galatians. Jesus didn't do these things in his life and so show a practical example of living as a Christ.

Comment: Welcome to the Biblical Hermeneutics Stack Exchange.  We are glad you stopped by and hope you stay. If you haven't done so already, you may want to check out how this site is [a little different](http://meta.hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/653/how-can-we-educate-new-users-about-our-site-distinctives#803) than other sites. *This is not a comment on the quality of your answer, but rather a standard welcome message.*

Answer (score 0):

Do you understand “everyone who believes in him” to include those who *don't believe Him* when He says something like: “if you would enter life, **keep the commandments**” (Matthew 19:17)? Certainly not, because:

> **1 John 2:4**
>
> If anyone says, "I know Him," [I believe in Him] **but does not keep His commandments,** he is **a liar,** and the truth is not in him. For **by this we know that we have known him:** *if we keep his commandments.*

So those who do not “by the Spirit put to death the deeds of the flesh..shall die.” (Romans 8:13).

The Bible does not teach the Protestant notions of 'once saved always saved' or 'sola fide.'

You simply cannot believe in Jesus and *not* obey Him. In fact obedience in Christ and obedience to Him are equated:

> **John 3:6**
>
> He that *believes* on the Son has everlasting life: and he that
>   *obeys not* the Son **shall not see life;** *but **the wrath of God** abideth
>   on him.*

Because to disobey Him is to not believe Him when He commands us to do something.

Jesus questions the validity of the discipleship of those who do not obey Him:

> **Luke 6:46 (parable)**
>
> 'Why do you call me 'Lord, Lord,' and do not do what I tell you?'
>
> **Matthew 7:21 (NOT parable)**
>
> *Not everyone who says to Me, 'Lord, Lord,' will enter the kingdom of
>   heaven,* **but he who does** the will of My Father who is in heaven.

And so say that if you are Christian you *'will not'* do sins ('begging the question' fallacy), and thus lose your right standing with God, justification (as if you can't give away a gift offered to you):

> **1 John 1:8**
>
> *If we say we have no sin, we deceive ourselves,* and the truth is not
>   in us.

Notice these last Scriptures are written by St. John who emphasizes faith the most.

St. Paul says likewise:

> **1 Corinthians 7:19**
>
> For neither circumcision counts for anything nor uncircumcision, but
>   keeping the commandments of God [is what matters].

The keeping of which commandments he calls “faith, expressed through love” (Galatians 5:6).

---

In other words, in the New Covenant, we are expected to put to death the deeds of the flesh by the power of the Holy Ghost:

> **Romans 8:13**
>
> For **if you live according to the flesh, you shall die**: but *if* **by the Spirit** you **put to death the deeds of the flesh,** *you shall live*.
>
> **^ 2:6-8**
>
> For he will repay **according to each one's deeds:** to those who by patiently **doing good** seek for glory and honor and immortality, ***he will give eternal life;*** but for those who are self-seeking and who **obey not** the truth but wickedness, **there will be wrath and fury.**

### Conclusion

---

> **James 1:22**
>
> But be **doers of the word,** and not hearers only, in so doing
>   *deceiving yourselves*.

Our Lord Jesus, in His hyperbolic fashion, tells us also we must put to death the way of the world or we will be cast into Hell:

> **Matthew 5:29**
>
> And if thy right eye *scandalize thee,* pluck it out and *cast it from
>   thee.* For it is **expedient for thee** that one of thy members should
>   perish, **rather than that thy whole body be cast into Hell.**